# Unable to delete account after revote

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, deleted-accounts

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/339911) I can delete [my account](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/73704/alexolut) if I have never voted or never posted more than once.

Currently I see no votes but already earned a Supporter badge (probably because of voting with revoking that voice after)

> [image: novotes]

Despite of 0 votes in my profile I can't delete account by myself (there's no option):

> [image: nodelete]

What's is the reason to disable account self-deletion if all my votes is actually revoked? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cast 4 votes. You did retract them, but the criteria for immediate self-deletion allow you to cast at most *one* vote.

You can still delete your account by going to the ["contact us" page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/contact) and filling out the delete request form.

Comment: Is it possible to see these 4 votes in my profile or somewhere else?

Comment: @alexolut Not without access to dev tools, no.